# update table1 with data from table2

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, transition

after reading many forums and trying many exemples, i still can't seem convert my old mySQL Query into SQL Server 2008. many exemples ive read consist of updating the column from table 1 when it finds a single value in table 2. the old mySQL script that i was using was

```
UPDATE stock.tbldesk_inv As T1
inner JOIN stock.deskinvfix AS T2 ON T1.serial_number = T2.SN
SET T1.location = T2.Location, 
T1.asset_number = T2.AssNumber, 
T1.department = T2.dept, 
T1.status = T2.Status, 
T1.first_name = T2.firstn, 
T1.last_name = T2.lastn;
DELETE FROM stock.deskinvfix;
SELECT * FROM stock.deskinvfix;
```

i find it frustrating that i can simply change the table names to re-use a simple querys

Because i can't rebrand my table as T1 or T2 it makes the new query hard to follow. personnaly i wish i could have stayed on mySQL.

```
UPDATE [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[Hardware_Inventory] SET
[InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[Hardware_Inventory].ComputerName = [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[updatepcname].SCCMName
FROM   [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[Hardware_Inventory]
INNER JOIN [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[updatepcname] ON [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[Hardware_Inventory]
WHERE [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[Hardware_Inventory].SerialNumber = [InventoryDatabase].[dbo].[updatepcname].SCCMSerial
```

can anyone tell me why SQL server doesn't like mySQL query i was using?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, just a few tips to make your query more readable and easier to follow.

If I understand what you mean by "rebrand" you certainly can do that in SQL Server. It is called a [table alias](technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx).

You don't need to qualify your tables with "[InventoryDatabase]" if when running the query from the InventoryDatabase since that would be the default. You don't need to specify "[dbo]" either since it is the default owner.

Give those things a try and then maybe we can get at why SQL Server doesn't like your query.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why can't I have more than one paragraph or use Markdown in a comment? Seems odd.

Comment: it should be as simple as this but i get invaild objects from the SQL Management Studio

' UPDATE Hardware_Inventory as t1 
SET T1.ComputerName = T2.SCCMName
FROM
INNER JOIN updatepcname as T2 ON T1.SerialNumber = T2.SCCMSerial '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.ComputerName = T2.SCCMName 
FROM Hardware_Inventory as T1
INNER JOIN updatepcname as T2 ON T1.SerialNumber = T2.SCCMSerial
```

Noel

Comment: when i first tried that query i was still getting multi-part identifier errors. but after i turned off IntelliSense the query worked. I'm a little confused why IntelliSense would cause issues.

Comment: Very odd. Not sure about that.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. this will help me mass edit the inventory database.